# Is it unnecessary to specify public or public abstract in the code below?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

```
interface Airplane {
     String fuelOption = "kerosene";
     
     public abstract String getFuelOption();
}
```

Is it necessary to specify public or public abstract in the line with the getFuelOption() method?
Thank you!

Comment: All interface methods are both `public` and `abstract` by default.

Comment: It is unnecessary.

Comment: I did... I just wanted to make sure and I saw some people using the key words regardless.. sorry this is my first question.. geez.

Comment: If you did, then you would have found a definitive answer and not bothered to post. The two people who provided answers answered within just a few minutes, which is atypical for this site. Why? Because the answer was incredibly easy to find via search. You don't need to put on a fig leaf to save face -- all you need to do is to understand that this site values efficiency and move on with that knowledge. Read the help file section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

The **public access modifier** is not needed because

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
> public (§6.6). It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style,
> to redundantly specify the public modifier for a method declaration in
> an interface. (Section 9.4)

The **abstract access modifier** is not needed because

> A default method is a method that is declared in an interface with the
> default modifier; its body is always represented by a block.

And...

An interface method lacking a default modifier or a static modifier is implicitly abstract, so its body is represented by a semicolon, not a block.

Given that default methods have a body, and those that don't are inherently abstract, and every method declaration on an interface is inherently public, you don't need to specify either keyword.

Please refer below JLS :

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#:~:text=Every%20method%20declaration%20in%20the,method%20declaration%20in%20an%20interface.&text=Default%20methods%20are%20distinct%20from,which%20are%20declared%20in%20classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#:%7E:text=Every%20method%20declaration%20in%20the,method%20declaration%20in%20an%20interface.&text=Default%20methods%20are%20distinct%20from,which%20are%20declared%20in%20classes).

Comment: Upvoted, but it would be good to link to the JLS sections that you quoted.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, updated the answer with JLS.

Comment: Thank you! I remember reading this but I wanted to double check because some examples I saw included those keywords any way.

Answer (score 1):

No, All `interface` methods are `public` and `abstract` by default.

relevant text from the [Java language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/jls15.pdf), Section 9.4

> A method in the body of an interface may be declared public or private .If no access modifier is given, the method is implicitly
> public.
>
> An interface method lacking a private, default, or static modifier is
> implicitly abstract. Its body is represented by a semicolon, not a
> block.